# How to get a list of Service Endpoints using REST API for TFS 2015 on prem instance?

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015

I am using the REST based API for the TFS 2015 to get list of Service Endpoints (as per the [reference](https://www.visualstudio.com/it-it/docs/integrate/api/endpoints/endpoints)). But facing an issue while extracting the information.

We have an on prem instance of TFS 2015 (Version 14.102.25423.0). Below is the URL I am trying to get the list of service endpoints.

https://tfs-on-prem-instance/DefaultCollection/product-name/_apis/distributedtask/serviceendpoints?api-version=3.0-preview.1

**Error:**

**In Browser**

```
{"count":1,"value":{"Message":"An error has occurred."}}
```

**In PowerShell**

> Invoke-RestMethod : {"count":1,"value":{"Message":"An error has
>   occurred."}} At D:\DevOps\TFS\TFSServiceModule.psm1:75 char:23 + ...
>   $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -Credential $Cred
>   ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ +
>   CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpW
>   ebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell
>   .Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Could anyone let me know how can I fix this? Or refer me to some additional documentation to go through.

Comment: Do you have access to the server to check the Windows event logs? Also, what is the exact on-premise version you have?

Comment: I don't have an access to the server. But I am able to call any other available API like Service Endpoint Types, Get/Create Release definition etc.

Comment: Version 14.102.25423.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the ID of the project via [Get a team project](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/projects#get-a-team-project) rest API first and then use the ID of the project to get the service endpoints via the [Service Endpoints](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/endpoints/endpoints) API. So the URL should like this:

```
http://tfsinstance/CollectionName/**PROJECTID**/_apis/distributedtask/serviceendpoints?api-version=3.0-preview.1
```

Comment: I used the method mentioned here[endpoint information api](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/distributedtask/taskagentrestclient/taskagenthttpclient2_1), but I got  an error message "TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required." when using getServiceEndpointDetails() , with a response status 401

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT in a custom widget page

Comment: @sify Please create a new question and share your detailed code there so that we can help you check the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested with TFS 2015 Update 3 (14.102.25423.0), but also got error when ran the api below:

```
Get http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/CollectionName/TeamProjectName/_apis/distributedtask/serviceendpoints?api-version=3.0-preview.1
```

This API works fine on VSTS and TFS 15 RC 2, but doesn't work on TFS 2015.3. I have submitted a feedback at website below, you can vote it:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3111161

Comment: Is there any workaround exist to retrieve the list of Service Endpoints?

Comment: Currently, there is no workaround to retrieve the list of Service Endpoints except checking on web access UI. Let's track the feedback to see whether they can help us to solve the issue or provide a workaround.